# get recent tweets from twitter using API 1.1

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth, tweets

I want to get recent tweets from twitter using API 1.1 .

I just don't want to get it only for current user or user's followers. I want to get all the tweets from all the users.

Is there a way by which I can get all user's tweets. 
Is there any limit for this type of API call?

I want to fetch all the tweets at the application level, that means I won't be having any user token.  How I can do this?

**EDIT:**

I found that we can use **SEARCH** API to search recent tweets using this

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets

But In this API we have to pass the **q** parameter to search. But what if I don't want search based on specific parameter. I just want all the tweets from last 24 hours.

Is there way where I don't have to pass **q** in search API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to call

```
https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/sample.json
```

This will allow you to get a [random sample of the most recent tweets made by all users](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/sample).

Comment: It's a stream. You will get a continual sample of public tweets. You can use a library to limit them to a certain number if you wish.

Comment: do u happen to know any library for this ?

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure there isn't any way to get all the tweets from all users at **an application level**. What you want to do is have your application store a version of each users tweet in a DB and then query the DB for that information.  This approach also doesn't come with any call limits.

You look at a list of the available Twitter API v1.1 calls available in its REST API at:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1

The only application level call is:

```
GET application/rate_limit_status
```

Comment: Is there any other way to get all user's tweets ?

Comment: If you now who the user's are you should be able to query their timeline.  When they user your application you would need to store their token/key and then use that (then or at a later time) to query their timeline.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But I don't want to query particular's user's time line. I want to fetch all user's tweets.

Comment: Then the 'solution' I suggested is the only way to go.  Should be easy to implement. What problem do you see? I am curious.

Comment: sorry, which solution ?

Comment: What you want to do is have your application store a version of each users tweet in a DB and then query the DB for that information.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45878/discussion-between-bsthakrar-and-metablocks-corp)